# importing mysqlclient in visual basic.net

Tags: vb.net, mysql

Can anyone help me on how can I import "System.Data.MySqlClient" in visual basic.net?

When I'm typing that code it produce an underline to the code and having an error of undefined namespace. How will I do?

Answer (score 6):

1. Download and install the lastest .NET-Connector from [www.mysql.com](http://www.mysql.com).
2. Add the MySQL.Data in Visual Studio to your project references (Menu: project, Properties, References).
3. Code!